# AJAX call to hit a URL

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to hit a page using an AJAX call

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/path/addId?type=one&id=' + $("#id").val(),
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data){
      alert(data[message]);
    },
    error: function(data){
      alert("error!");
    }
});
```

I'm getting an error for this. What is the basic configuration required to hit external URL?

UPDATE:

Here's the response I'm getting or error:

```
readyState
getResponseHeader
getAllResponseHeaders
setRequestHeader
overrideMimeType
statusCode
abort
state
always
then
promise
pipe
done
fail
progress
complete
success
error
respondedText
status
statusText
```

Comment: Few notes : you're confusing GET and POST methods (by appending params in your URL and setting POST method explicitly) - and your URL doesn't look external to me (it's a relative path).

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Comment: What do you mean "external" url? are you trying to hit different domain?

Comment: It is a relative path

Comment: what about `alert(data)`?? ajax does not return arrays. you have to `json_encode()` them from php and `JSON.parse()` them in javascript, for exemple, to access the value contained in `data[message]`

Comment: What type of response you are expecting from your _external_ url.

Comment: if no id is present then {"message": "id not present"}. Otherwise {"message": "true"} or {"message": "false"}

Comment: "I need to hit a page using an AJAX call" did you mean an `HTML`page..?! can you be more specific..?

Comment: I'm hitting an API on this page. I want to add the id I pass.

Answer (score 1):

What Bigood said is true.. you are getting confused between POST and GET.

To use GET use below code:

```
$.ajax({
 url: '/path/addId?type=one&id=' + $("#id").val(),
 type: "GET",
 success: function(data){
  alert(data[message]);
 },
 error: function(data){
  alert("error!");
 }
});
```

to use POST use below code

```
var id=$("#id").val();
$.ajax({
 url: '/path/addId',
 type: "POST",
 data: {type:'one',id:id},
 success: function(data){
  alert(data[message]);
 },
 error: function(data){
  alert("error!");
 }
});// indentation
```

Comment: sending get variables with post ajax works, by the way. It might not be good practice, but it does work.

Comment: @vinayajk neither of these are working. I'm still getting an error

Comment: Paulie: can you paste the exact response that you are getting from browser console.

Comment: what you have given in post is not response its the AJAX's xhr object.

Comment: how exactly do i get this?

Comment: If you are using chrome, press F12, goto Network tab. clear the console..there is clear button.. now do the AJAX call in your page.. now you can see something in the network tab.. click on it and you can see the request , response everything..

Comment: method:GET, statusText: (canceled), Type: Pending

Comment: Still not the response I am looking for.. anyways can you please goto console tab and paste the contents here.

Comment: it's giving a 500 error, so that's why the AJAX call is failing.

Comment: See my answer - the AJAX call isn't failing. The 500 response code indicates that an error occurred on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the alert window saying 'error!', it means that your ajax request was being sent successfully, but that the server is responding with an error, or not at all.

This could be for a number of reasons, but I would firstly check that your URL is correct.

Comment: Please have a look at my update. The URL is correct, I am able to access it.